# How do I access google drive files with the same name in 2 different folders - Python

Tags: python

I am currently trying to access files with the same name in different google drive folders but do not know how to code this. Below is the file paths and names of the files that I am trying to access.

```
/content/drive/My Drive/Jacob_Images/Ground_Truths/a (3).jpg
/content/drive/My Drive/Jacob_Images/Ground_Truths/a (7).jpg
/content/drive/My Drive/Jacob_Images/Ground_Truths/a (6).jpg

/content/drive/My Drive/Jacob_Images/Originals/a (3).jpg
/content/drive/My Drive/Jacob_Images/Originals/a (7).jpg
/content/drive/My Drive/Jacob_Images/Originals/a (6).jpg
```

Below is the code, that I started to make but I am unable to finish it. There are several files in each folder that is why there is an *.

```
file = '/content/drive/My Drive/Jacob_Images/Originals/*.jpg'
mask = '/content/drive/My Drive/Jacob_Images/Ground_Truths/*.jpg'
glob.glob(file)
glob.glob(mask)

for x in glob.glob(file):
  for y in glob.glob(mask):
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you want to do with this files? are you trying to open them if they are in both folder? Or check the ones that are in one and not the other, or the ones that are in both?

Comment: They are different images in different folders but they have the  same names, ideally I would like to check to see if they both are the same shape and then compare them pixel by pixel.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the easiest way I can think of would be something like that

```py
import os

original_folder = "data/originals"
ground_truth_folder = "data/ground_truths"

# get file names of all files in folder without the whole path
original_images = os.listdir(original_folder )
ground_truth_images = os.listdir(ground_truth_folder)

for img in original_images:
    # For every images in the original folder, check if it is in the Ground_truth one
    if img in ground_truth_images
        print(f"{img} is in {original_folder} and {ground_truth_folder}"):
        # Do your comparison here
        same_shape, same_img = compare_images(img, original_folder,ground_truth_folder)
        
    else:
        print(f"{img} is in {original_folder} but not in {ground_truth_folder}")
```

For your comparison you could have a function like below, that returns both if they have the same shape and if it's the same image:

```py
def compare_images(img,original_folder, ground_truth_folder):
    original_img = np.array(Image.open(os.path.join(original_folder, img)))
    ground_truth_img = np.array(Image.open(os.path.join(ground_truth_folder, img)))
    return original_img.shape == ground_truth_img.shape, np.all(original_img == ground_truth_img)
```